# Soft-body works with 2.79b but doesn't with 2.8x (including 2.82a)

Tags: soft-body

I'm having difficulties with soft-body simulations since 2.8x.
I presume this is not a bug as the version 2.80 has been released for months, and it would have been noticed...

If I parent a soft-body to an object (an empty in this example), the simulation is not stable and glitches a lot. This behavior is the same for all the tests I have made (v2.80-2.81-2.82a)
If I take the exact same object in version 2.79b it's working correcly.
Any idea of what I'm doing wrong or what's has been changed? Do you think this is a bug?

Thanks!

**Version 2.82a (glitches) :**

[image: Soft body in 2.82a, glitches]

**Version 2.79b (works OK):**

[image]